# How do I configure a DbContext with dependency injection with .Net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string cs = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Skillcheck"); 
    services.AddDbContext<TicketsystemContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cs));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Context

```
public TicketsystemContext()
{
}

public TicketsystemContext(DbContextOptions<TicketsystemContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

// ... rest of the context
```

Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been
>   configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by
>   overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext
>   on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then
>   also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a
>   DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to
>   the base constructor for DbContext.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider
>   scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ChangeTracker()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter[TDeclaringType,TValue](Func`2
>   getter, Object target)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.BindModelCoreAsync(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext
>   actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider,
>   ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()

Exception when I remove the empty constructor from the context

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
>   'Skillcheck.Models.TicketsystemContext'. Model bound complex types
>   must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless
>   constructor. Alternatively, give the 'c' parameter a non-null default
>   value.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.BindModelCoreAsync(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext
>   actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider,
>   ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()

- cs in the Service isn't null and reads the string from
  appsettings.json successfully
- after services.AddDbContext the context is in the ServiceCollection
  and it doesn't throw
- using the generic DbContextOptions instead of
  DbContextOptions < TicketsystemContext > in the context constructor
  doesn't work
- explicitly adding a IHttpContextAccessor doesn't work either

I temporarily solved it by overriding OnConfiguring, but I want to understand why it's not working.
I'm using .Net Core 2.1 on VS2017.

**Solution**

The error was that instead of

```
private TicketsystemContext _c;

public HomeController(TicketsystemContext c)
{
    _c = c;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_c.User.First());
}
```

I used

```
public IActionResult Index(TicketsystemContext c)
{
    return View(c.User.First());
}
```

which works when overriding OnConfiguring, but doesn't when configuring while injecting.

Comment: Your code does look ok. Have you explicitly registered IHttpContextAccessor as well?
`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Comment: @Mausam: That is totally unnecessary and has nothing to do with the issue here.

Comment: Which line throw the second error? A reproducable demo would be helpful.

Comment: @Mausam I've already tried that, but have forgot to mention it. I've added it now.

Comment: @TaoZhou The Run in CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); throws it. The Startup.Configure Method doesn't show any problems, so it throws after that. I think Chris is onto something so I'll wait until I try to reproduce.

Comment: If there is no demo, you may consider share us the complete `TicketsystemContext` and `Startup`, I will try to check whether could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou I've managed to [reproduce](http://www.mediafire.com/file/p078y3y2qkr272r/SkillcheckReproduce.zip/file) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first error is due to the inclusion of a parameterless constructor. That should not be present. Dependency injection will always choose the constructor with the least dependencies to satisfy, which would be the parameterless, but you *need* `DbContextOptions<TContext>` injected.

The second error indicates that you're including the context as a param in an action method. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but you shouldn't. Your context should be injected into the controller itself and set to an ivar on that, so you actions can utilize the ivar. You *may* be able to prefix the param with `[FromServices]` to indicate that the modelbinder should ignore it and it should be injected from the service collection, instead, but method injection is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm using an action method. I've added the complete ConfigureService for clarity.

Comment: It would be in one of your controllers, not your Startup. In other words, after you remove the parameterless constructor, you're good. The second error is an entirely different issue.

Comment: The parameterless constructor didn't matter but I'll keep what you said in mind. In the end it was what you said, with injecting directly into the controller. I just didn't understand the lingo, before the code from Tao.

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting `TicketsystemContext` into `Index` action directly.

In general, you should inject `TicketsystemContext` as dependence into contructor like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly TicketsystemContext context;
    public HomeController(TicketsystemContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(context.User.First());
    }
}
```

If you perfer inject `TicketsystemContext` to action, you could try the suggestion from @Chris Pratt by code below:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromServices]TicketsystemContext c)
{
    return View(c.User.First());
}
```